# Vue.js form data binding lost when browser going back to the page

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

Here is what I am doing :
I have a form set component that fetch data through ajax to populate the form set.
The user may modify those datas from the form and submit.

Problem : This work well. However, I noticed that if i navigate to another page and then hit the browser "go back one page" button, the form is there (the DOM in the template) but empty.
There is no data bound in v-model input fields anymore...

Most posts about this behavior are connected to vue-router, that I do not use.

I think it might have to deal with lifecycle hooks...
Actually, on my component, I fetch the data when "mounted".
But, if so, which lifecycle ?

I also tried "keep-alive" without success.

I put some verbose log on my component to try to catch the lifecycle hook when browser going back and none of them printed...

```
beforeCreate: function() {
    console.log('---- BEFORE CREATE ----> ')
},
created: function() {
    console.log('---- CREATED ----> ')
    this.getModelObjects();
},
beforeMount: function() {
    console.log('---- BEFORE MOUNT ----> ')
},
mounted: function() {
    console.log('---- MOUNTED ---->')
    this.getModelObjects();
},
beforeUpdate: function() {
    console.log('---- BEFORE update ----> ')
},
updated: function() {
    console.log('---- UPDATED ----> ')
},
beforeDestroy: function() {
    console.log('---- BEFORE DESTROY ----> ')
},
destroyed: function() {
    console.log('----  DESTROYED ----> ')
},
```

Any idea?

Comment: `keep-alive` will only work in this case if you're navigating with `vue-router` throughout your pages. If you actually perform a refresh or or a full page load, then this method won't work. Maybe what you want is `vuex` or a `localStorage` solution.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for the guidance you provided! I will look for localStorage first and keep this post updaded. It's good to know the behaviour I described seems normal :-)

Comment: There is a Vuex plugin that stores it's data in localStorage on the fly: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-localstorage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I solved this problem in the most easiest way possible!

Actually, using `localStorage` (https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html), would not solve the problem.

In anyway, it needs to be tied to a lifecycle hook in order to be triggered. Therefore, as I already sync those datas on a backend database with Axios, this would add redundant complexity and end up with the same problem.

I also noticed that only v-model fields where concerned. {{ var }} were not. So, I ended up thinking this was really related to forms.

**Instead, I used `autocomplete="on"` in my forms.**

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="on">
.....
</form>
```

But, in fact, autocomplete is "on" by default :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

> The persistence feature is enabled by default. Setting the value of
>   the autocomplete attribute to off disables this feature.

I don't remember why, but I used `autocomplete="off"` in my forms :-( ...
This might be why I don't see much posts about it...

Now, if a user click to a link on the page, and then navigate backward with the "go one page back" button, v-model binded fields are there.

Comment: Wow I had same problem and I spent many hours trying to find a solution. Thank you!