# Firefox don't trigger vuejs hooks when clicking back browser history button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firefox, browser-history

I have a problem related to Vue.js and the browser history in Firefox.

I have a simple Vue.js form to modify accounts that is embedded in a legacy laravel app.
Basically, I set values in Vue.js using blade syntax like so:

```
<div id="vueApp">
    <vue-form :customer="{{ json_encode($customer) }}"></form>
</div>
```

And use the created hook to set fields in vue (in order to be modified):

```
data: function() {
    return {
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        //...
    }
},
created: function() {
   this.firstName = this.customer.first_name;
   this.lastName = this.customer.last_name;
   //...
}
```

All those variables are shown using `v-model` in `input` markup.

The vue app is used to perform some formatting and front validations, and at the end,
the form is submitted like an old html form (with a `button type="submit"`)

Everything works fine except when I try to access to this form by clicking to the backward history button of Firefox, in that case, all the values of the `input` are empty.
Wierdly enough, the Vue data are set like they should.

I only have this bug in Firefox (73.0.1) , I checked in Chrome and Safari.

I investigated a little, and it seem that Vue.js don't triggers any lifecycle hooks in the case you clicked go back in browser history.

Is there something I don't understand ? Or is this a bug, maybe with a workaround ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use the "mounted" hook instead of the "created" hook because it is called only once after instantiation?

Comment: I got the same problem with the `mounted` hook. I tried to console.log a message on every hooks, and really, none of them is triggered when I press "back".
I tried to do so with an empty Vue.js component, and I have the same problem.

Comment: Ok so, It seem that that issue was related to the use of `autocomplete="off"` as seen in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762493/vue-js-form-data-binding-lost-when-browser-going-back-to-the-page?rq=1
So I don't really know how to fix that because in that app we really need to don't show the autocomplete widget :/
 Thanks for the help !