# Vue v-model breaks after history forward, history back

Tags: html, vue.js, input

local index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <form action="/sign" method="POST">
        <input v-model="zip" id="zip" type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      {{ zip }}
    </div>
    <script>
      const App = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          zip: ''
        },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

We open this in chrome.  After entering something in the input box, we can see in the chrome console that v-model is correct:

App.zip and document.querySelector('#zip').value are the same.

If we then navigate to a new site (www.google.com, etc.), and then hit back on the browser to go back to the index.html file,

App.zip = ''
and
document.querySelector('#zip').value is = to what we put in before.

Is this documented and expected?  Can we make it so that App.zip tracks this correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Trying specifically adding autocomplete="on" to your form. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762493/vue-js-form-data-binding-lost-when-browser-going-back-to-the-page

Comment: Try add autocomplete="off" to your form element. [Vue.js form data binding lost when browser going back to the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52927547/10475870)

Answer (score 0):

That's back-forward cache (at least the implementation on Chrome).

In a real scenario bfcache is disabled because the app is either on https or because it's not cached (header `Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store`)

Answer (score -1):

I could not comment, I wrote as an answer because my score was not enough. I think you should take a look here. https://vuex.vuejs.org/