# Vue reactivity fails when navigating back to the page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, browser-cache

I use a simple binary **Vue** variable named `binary_state` to control the class of an element, named "controlled_element" in the rest of this question. "controlled_element" has two classes "class_true" and "class_fasle" as determined by the value of `binary_state`. The value of `binary_state` itself switches between true and false using a button on the page. Let's call that button "controlling_element".

Every time the value of `binary_state` changes using "controlling_element", the updated value is sent to the server. On the other hand, every time the page is refreshed, an updated value for `binary_state` is retrieved from the server. Once that happens, the class of the "controlled_element" gets adjusted too.

It is a pretty straightforward scenario. Now consider the following steps:

1. Refresh the page, so a fresh value of `binary_state` gets retrieved from the server. For simplicity, let's assume the fresh value is `true`, i.e., `binary_state=true`. This will set the class of "controlled_element" to "class_true".
2. Press the "controlling_element" an odd number of times. This will set `binary_state` and the class of "controlled_element" to "false" and "class_false", respectively.
3. Navigate away from the page and come back to it using the back arrow (button) of the browser.
4. I expect the value of `binary_state` to continue to be `false`. That *seems* to be actually the case, as seen on the Vue devtool plugin.
5. I also expect the class of "controlled_element" to continue to be "class_false". However, to my surprise, the class is "class_true", which is the latest value **received** from the server regardless of all the changes that were applied in step 2.

Note that when navigating back to the page, the sync (reactivity) between `binary_state` and the class of "controlled_element" gets violated: As mentioned in step 4 above, the value of `binary_state` continues to be false (as indicated by the Vue devtool plugin), but the class of "controlled_element" is "class_true".

**NOTE.** I have seen this issue in chrome (Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Edge (108.0.1462.76 (Official build) (64-bit)), but *everything* is fine with Firefox (108.01.1 (64-bit)).

Three final remarks.

- I have seen this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762493/vue-js-form-data-binding-lost-when-browser-going-back-to-the-page). The author indicates they were able to solve the issue by setting `autocomplete="on"` of the form. I am not sure if that is helpful for me, because I do not have a form, to begin with.
- I have seen some suggestions on using `vuex` or `localStorage`, but I am not sure if that is necessary in my case because, as mentioned in step 4, the Vue value `binary_state` seems to have the correct value.
- I am *not* using `vue-router` if that has a bearing on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest, I have some suggestions depending on which version of vue you are using. For example, if you are using `Vue2` or `Vue3` with the cli, your state management problems can be solved with `Vuex` (however at this point `vuex` is not the officially recommended state management system anymore). The best solution, if you're using `Vue3`, is to go with `Pinia` https://pinia.vuejs.org which is very helpful, modern, and surprisingly easier to learn and use, compared to `Vuex`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
`localStorage` is an alternate solution, but the tradeoff is that you will have to write code to erase that `localStorage`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
`sessionStorage` is similar to `localStorage` but will automatically erase the data after the window closes.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! One point is that, as I mentioned in Step 4, the Vue variable seems to be correct based on what is shown in the Vue devtools plugin. This gives me some hope that the problem can be solved without using browser storage or Pinia. That being said, the sync between the Vue variable and the corresponding element class fails upon revisiting the page using the back button. Do you have any ideas on how to re-establish the connection between them? I am using Vue.js v2.6.12.

Comment: I guess I need to learn to re-establish a new Vue two-way binding even if I use the solutions based on the browser storage and Piani. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by manually reloading the page when a user visits the page using the browser back/forward buttons. The following code snippet does it:

```js
<script>
    if (performance) {
        // get the PerformanceNavigationTiming object
        const perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");
        const perfNavTiming = perfEntries && perfEntries[0];

        if (perfNavTiming) {
            // get the type of navigation
            const navType = perfNavTiming.type;

            // reload if it is back_forward or prerender.
            if ((navType === "back_forward") ||
                (navType === "prerender")) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

It is not the neatest solution, but I guess I should go for it, given my time limit. I guess some learning is required before I can use the suggested solutions using `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, and `Piani`, as I am not sure how to use these techniques to re-initiate the Vue two-way binding.